# After upgrade to Magento ee 1.13 javascript breaks on single quote translations

Tags: magento-enterprise, javascript, localisation, enterprise-1.13, prototype-js

I have recently upgraded an environment from a french customer form ee1.11 to ee1.13.

I am getting javascript errors allover for strings with single quotes, Alltough this was fixed a few versions ago the problem now turned up again.

While waiting for a response from Magento i would like to ask if anyone had any experience with this / has a possible temporary solution.

Example error below:

```
 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 

'Qu'est-ce que c'est ?',
```

Comment: Stating the obvious maybe, but it looks like the texts used in js are not escaped anymore.

Comment: I agree, just can't find where the change is made, tried a diff with meld and am going trough it now.

Comment: Have you done the usual? Disabling any minification (both core/3rd party) wiped `var/cache` or `var/full_page_cache` manually?

Comment: I did more, I always have a seperate testing environment of the version I'm using, i tested it there. It is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was confirmed as a corebug, Magento gave the patch and as stated they fixed escaping the js. You can just contact Magento for the patch.